# Difference between linear and logarithmic z-buffer

Tags: opengl, glsl, depth-buffer, vertex-shader

I've searched about this topic for awhile and i couldn't find it on google. I've come across several ways to avoid z-fighting which are linear z-buffer, logarithmic z-buffer and reversed z-buffer. I decided to leave reversed z-buffer for now as i'm not planning to use OpenGL 4.5. The thing is i don't know the difference between linear and logarithmic z-buffer.

By "linear" i mean this:

```
float fz = gl_Position.z * gl_Position.w;
gl_Position.z = (fz - near) * 2.0 / (far - near) - 1.0;
```

And by "logarithmic" i mean this:

```
float w = gl_Position[3];
float C = 0.001;
gl_Position.z = (2 * log(C * w + 1) / log(C * far + 1) - 1) * w;
```

If i understand those codes correctly, the linear try to map all of the z value evenly. So does the logarithmic one. Sure both of them are totally different but i have tried both and see no or if any minimal differences, both eliminate the z-fighting. So there must be something i missed or don't understand.

**edit:** As Jimmy said, logarithmic is better than linear. Please add why logarithmic is better than linear z-buffer as i want to know why it is better and not just which one is better.

Comment: naive Z < linear Z < log Z in terms of consistency of number of depth bits available at all levels. If linear Z is enough to eliminate-fighting for you, it's probably faster to use that than to use log Z.

Answer (score -2):

A logaritmic z-buffer provides more accuracy for objects near the camera in exchange for a drop in precision for far away objects. In comparison a linear z-buffer provides uniform precision for all distances and it's a bit faster.

You should try to find which algorithm fits your game best. e.g If you are developing a game with closeup elements like a FPS a logaritmic z-buffer may be the best for you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that' not a common case where one would want to use logarithmic z-buffer.